# Error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1?

Tags: php, mysqli

where is error.....
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $data);
    $save = "INSERT INTO SONG_AS(ALBUM, CATEGORY, SUB_CATEGORY,
        SONG_NAME, ARTIST, ART_LINK, 
        YEAR, GENRE, SONG_LINK, POST_ON, 
        POST_BY, TOTAL_DOWNLOAD) 
            VALUES('$albm', '$cat', '$scat', "
            . "'$sn', '$art', '$img', "
            . "'$y', '$g', "
            . "'$sl', '$time', '', '0')";


    $success = mysqli_query($conn, $save) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $page = "index.php";
    $this->pageRedirect($page);
```

where is error.....
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Post your errors, Post your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$save = "INSERT INTO SONG_AS(`ALBUM`, `CATEGORY`, `SUB_CATEGORY`,
                    `SONG_NAME`, `ARTIST`, `ART_LINK`, 
                    `YEAR`, `GENRE`, `SONG_LINK`, `POST_ON`, 
                `POST_BY`, `TOTAL_DOWNLOAD`) 
        VALUES('".$albm."', '".$cat."', '".$scat."','".$sn."', '".$art."', '".$img."', '".$y."', '".$g."', '".$sl."', '".$time."', '', '0')";
```

Answer (score 1):

remove '' from your query to be:

```
$save = "INSERT INTO SONG_AS(ALBUM, CATEGORY, SUB_CATEGORY,
        SONG_NAME, ARTIST, ART_LINK, 
        YEAR, GENRE, SONG_LINK, POST_ON, 
        POST_BY, TOTAL_DOWNLOAD) 
            VALUES('$albm', '$cat', '$scat','$sn', '$art', '$img', '$y', '$g', '$sl', '$time', '', '0')";
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe I suck at counting, but I am only counting 12 values.

Comment: If you suck, so do I :P

Comment: Haha, phew, was getting worried for myself there. 
Well looks like your answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO employee VALUES ($empno','$lname','$fname','$init','$gender','$bdate','$dept','$position','$pay','$dayswork','$otrate','$othrs','$allow','$advancesance,'')";
    $msg = "New record saved!";
  }
  else {
    $query = "UPDATE employee SET empno=$empno','lname='$lname',fname='$fname',init= '$init',gender='$gender',bdate='$bdate',dept='$dept',position='$position',pay=$pay,dayswork=$dayswork,otrate=$otrate,othrs=$othrs,allow=$allow,advances=$advances,insurance=$insurance WHERE empno = $empno";
    $msg = "Record updated!";
  }
```